# global variables (memory binding)

Tags: c, static, global-variables

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a=0;

int main()
{
//some code
}
```

I have learned that physical memory binding for static variables is done at loadtime.
When is the memory binding done for 'a'? And where is it stored, in the stack area or static area?

Comment: This is platform-dependent.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth can you give an intuition why is it so?

Comment: Because the arrangement of memory, variables, etc. is not defined by the C language.

Comment: Compile the program and look at the resulting object file. (objdump for GNU/linux) BTW: there is a return statement missing from main. (allowed in c99, but still sloppy) BTW: to look at the progam `in memory` you could use a debugger and inspect the value for `a`. Sideways: `a` **must** be in the object file, since other objects could refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, the general behavior is platform-dependent and thus there's no universally valid answer, but on most modern, "normal" systems, what happens is that the compiler generates a `.data` section in the resulting object file, containing the initialization values of the variables you define.

When you start the program, then, the program loader memory-maps that `.data` section directly from the executable file into the newly created process' virtual memory, available for your program to read from and write to (probably using some COW scheme to keep each process' copy private).

The term "memory binding" that you use is not part of the normal terminology, so I don't know exactly what you're asking, but perhaps this helps?

Comment: by memory binding I mean the time when a variable is allocated actual physical memory.

Comment: In that case, I think my answer addresses that: At program loading time. Though, strictly speaking, it is only allocated *virtual* memory at that time. Modern systems will, strictly speaking, only allocate physical memory once you actually pagefault that section in by touching it (and if you never write to it but only read it, your process may never get exclusive memory allocated at all, since the section may be sharable with other processes).

Answer (score 0):

`a` is in **static storage**, since it is *global*. Only the *local* variables of a function are on the *stack*.

You can use the `static` keyword in a function to make the storage type of that variable static, too.

However, `static` on globals has a different meaning (since they are already of static storage type): the symbol for the variable is not exported to the object file, so that variable will not be directly accessible from other modules (.c files).

Comment: Whilst this is the most common behaviour, this is not mandatory.  The compiler/platform is free to do anything it likes in terms of storage.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, the compiler knows "a" is a global variable and put "a" into the data section of the executable file. In that area, the executable file records the virtual address of "a". And when the executable is loaded into the operating system for running, and the "a" is used during running, the OS will map a physical address to the virtual address of "a". The rest code of the executable only needs to know the virtual address of "a" to access it, and the OS will do the mapping and go to the physical memory for reading/writing. And the virtual address of "a" is determined by the compiler during compiling.

For more knowledge, the book "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective" is a good source.